# I continue to get the error: " TypeError: 'str' object is not callable " when pressing one of the buttons

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

This is what I currently have. Whenever I press the button at the bottom, it gets the error and the window stays blank. The error also says

```
tennis_window = Toplevel()
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2136, in __init__self.title(root.title())
```

which I don't understand, also apologies, this is my first post so please let me know if i can clarify anything

```
#Create the main window
Main_Window = Tk()

#Main window title
Main_Window.title = ('Top Ten')

#Converting to photo image
Top_Ten_Pic = gif_to_PhotoImage(urlopen('random gif image url').read())

#Converting to photo image
Tennis_pic = (urlopen('random gif image url').read())


#Create a label to display the downloaded image
top_ten_label = Label(Main_Window, image = Top_Ten_Pic, height = 280, 
width = 400)
top_ten_label.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan = 3)

#command for top ten tennis window
def button_tennis():

    #new toplevel window
    tennis_window = Toplevel()

    #title the window
    tennis_window.title = ('Top Ten Tennis')


    #Create a label to display the downloaded image
    top_ten_label = Label(tennis_window, image = Tennis_pic, height = 280, 
    width = 400)
    top_ten_label.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan = 3)

    #start the windows event loop
    top_tennis.mainloop()

#Top ten tennis button (mainwindow)
tennis_button = Button(Main_Window, text = 'Top Ten Tennis', font = 
('Times     New Roman', 12), command = button_tennis)
tennis_button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)


Main_Window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I suspect you got the downvote because people can't run that code to reproduce the bug for themselves. It's _much_ better to post a [mcve]. Also, when you get an error message you should post the whole thing from the `Traceback (most recent call last):` line.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is and on what line. You are trying to call a string, almost as if you did `"foo"()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using it wrong, instead of:

```
tennis_window.title = ('Top Ten Tennis')
```

You need:

```
tennis_window.title('Top Ten Tennis')
```

etc...